# Multiline sed script error: newline can not be used as a string delimiter

Tags: sed, text-formatting

I am trying to get this `sed` command to work:

```
   sed -e \
     's|$API_URL|$(API_URL)|g ; \
      s|$API_KEY|$(API_KEY)|g ;  \
      s|$API_SECRET|$(API_SECRET)|g ;  \
      s|$API_SALT|$(API_SALT)|g ; \
      s|$STORAGE_FUNCTION|$(STORAGE_FUNCTION)|g ; \
      s|$STORAGE_ACCOUNT|$(STORAGE_ACCOUNT)|g ; \
      s|$STORAGE_CONTAINER|$(STORAGE_CONTAINER)|g' \
      ./src/environments/environment.template.ts > ./src/environments/environment.ts
```

I am replacing placeholders in a file:

```
export const environment = {
   api: {
     url: '$API_URL',
     key: '$API_KEY',
     secret: '$API_SECRET',
     salt: '$API_SALT'
   }
};
```

But I get this error:

> newline can not be used as a string delimiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual error comes from the fact that an arbitrary delimiter character may be used to delimit a regular expression when used as line addresses by prefixing the delimiter character with a backslash, as in

```
\@hello@d
```

which would delete each line matching the regular expression `hello`, just like

```
/hello/d
```

would.

However, newlines may not be used as a delimiter in this way. Hence the error.

---

The `sed` script does not need the escaped newlines as it is all within a single quoted string.  Remove the `\` at the end of each line of the actual `sed` editing script:

```
sed -e 's|$API_URL|$(API_URL)|g
        s|$API_KEY|$(API_KEY)|g
        s|$API_SECRET|$(API_SECRET)|g
        s|$API_SALT|$(API_SALT)|g
        s|$STORAGE_FUNCTION|$(STORAGE_FUNCTION)|g
        s|$STORAGE_ACCOUNT|$(STORAGE_ACCOUNT)|g
        s|$STORAGE_CONTAINER|$(STORAGE_CONTAINER)|g' \
    infile >outfile
```

Note that the `;` between statements are replaced by newlines. They are only needed between statements occupying the same line, as in `G;s/\n/ /`, for example.

Alternatively:

```
sed -e 's|$API_URL|$(API_URL)|g' \
    -e 's|$API_KEY|$(API_KEY)|g' \
    -e 's|$API_SECRET|$(API_SECRET)|g' \
    -e 's|$API_SALT|$(API_SALT)|g' \
    -e 's|$STORAGE_FUNCTION|$(STORAGE_FUNCTION)|g' \
    -e 's|$STORAGE_ACCOUNT|$(STORAGE_ACCOUNT)|g' \
    -e 's|$STORAGE_CONTAINER|$(STORAGE_CONTAINER)|g' \
    infile >outfile
```

Or,

```
sed "s/'\\$\([^']*\)'/'\$(\1)'/g" infile >outfile
```

to replace anything that looks like `'$something Whatever'` with `'$(something Whatever)'`.

Or,

```
sed 's/$\([A-Z_]*\)/$(\1)/g' infile >outfile
```

to replace things that look like `$SOME_THING` with `$(SOME_THING)` (slightly stricter on the allowed characters in the variable names, but does not care about the single quotes).